# How to add subscriber in contact list of sendgrid wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

I tried the SendGrid plugin but the plugin does not support **PHP 7.4** version.

Comment: You will need to add more details to improve this question.

Comment: I am trying to integrate the contact form to SendGrid Marketing Campaigns.

Answer (score 0):

use Zapier, it's easy to fetch data from your site and send/save it to your Campaigns without any coding.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion but i want to use Sendgrid